# Find POBOX using regular expression in oracle - PL/SQL

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

I want to extract pobox value from string appearing after word POBOX using regular expression in oracle - PL/SQL.
Below are some examples
I/p

```
1. COMPANY (W L L ) POBOX - 24440 DOHA QATAR TEL 4765888
2. STAR LIMITED POBOX PO KHUPARI PO KHUPARI, TQ-WADA,DIST-THANE 421312INDIA
3. LENNOX ACCOUNT POBOX - N-4875 SD- THE BAHAMAS
4. MEDHIN WEREDA 13, ADDIS ABABA, ETHIOPIA, POBOX- 1110-1668 //UA
5. UHTHOFF, SC POBOX M-2059 06000 MEXICO  
6. PHARMACIE AKWABA POBOX AVENUE ESPEREY 00000 ABIDJAN 45 (COTE D IVOIRE),
7. CAAS POBOX 1 .//SG 
8. CORAL TECH PETER MAYNARD CO BAY DEVEAUX STREETS 2ND FLOOR POBOX N-1000 
9. GULF OCEAN CENTRE - MONTAGU FORESHORE EAST BAY STREET POBOX SS -19084
10. AHMED SAEED DAMMAM 2044 31453 POBOX 011383-KSA 
11. MISR COMPRESSOR (CO) 10 TH OF INDUSTRIAL ZONE A-2 POBOX 1001
12. NOKIA AND NETWORKS OY C/O NSN FRANCE POBOX1 3 KARAPORTII
13. HEWLETT PACKARD EUROP BV POBOX 100- POBOX 100-CH-1217
14. DUMONT BERGMAN BIDER + CO., S.C. POBOX456 DELEGACION CUAUHTEMO MX
```

o/p

```
1. 24440
2. 421312
3. 4875
4. 1110-1668
5. 2059
6. 00000
7. 1
8. 1000
9. 19084
10. 011383
11. 1001
12. 1
13. 100
14. 456
```

Comment: What have you attempted to do to solve the problem? Show what code you currently have.

Comment: Hi, I tried something like REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(LINE,'[[:digit:]] |[[:digit:]-]+[[:digit:]]',INSTR(LINE,'POBOX')),'^-')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might help you out:

```
WITH the_table AS (SELECT '1. COMPANY (W L L ) POBOX - 24440 DOHA QATAR TEL 4765888' line FROM dual
                   UNION
                   SELECT '2. STAR LIMITED POBOX PO KHUPARI PO KHUPARI, TQ-WADA,DIST-THANE 421312INDIA' FROM dual
                   UNION
                   SELECT '3. LENNOX ACCOUNT POBOX - N-4875 SD- THE BAHAMAS' FROM dual
                   UNION
                   SELECT '4. MEDHIN WEREDA 13, ADDIS ABABA, ETHIOPIA, POBOX- 1110-1668 //UA' FROM dual
                   UNION
                   SELECT '5. UHTHOFF, SC POBOX M-2059 06000 MEXICO' FROM dual
                   UNION
                   SELECT '6. PHARMACIE AKWABA POBOX AVENUE ESPEREY 00000 ABIDJAN 45 (COTE D IVOIRE),' FROM dual
                   UNION
                   SELECT '7. CAAS POBOX 1 .//SG' FROM dual
                   UNION
                   SELECT '8. CORAL TECH PETER MAYNARD CO BAY DEVEAUX STREETS 2ND FLOOR POBOX N-1000' FROM dual
                   UNION
                   SELECT '9. GULF OCEAN CENTRE - MONTAGU FORESHORE EAST BAY STREET POBOX SS -19084' FROM dual
                   UNION
                   SELECT '10. AHMED SAEED DAMMAM 2044 31453 POBOX 011383-KSA' FROM dual
                   UNION
                   SELECT '11. MISR COMPRESSOR (CO) 10 TH OF INDUSTRIAL ZONE A-2 POBOX 1001' FROM dual
                   UNION
                   SELECT '12. NOKIA AND NETWORKS OY C/O NSN FRANCE POBOX1 3 KARAPORTII' FROM dual
                   UNION
                   SELECT '13. HEWLETT PACKARD EUROP BV POBOX 100- POBOX 100-CH-1217' FROM dual
                   UNION
                   SELECT '14. DUMONT BERGMAN BIDER + CO., S.C. POBOX456 DELEGACION CUAUHTEMO MX' FROM dual)                   
SELECT line, REGEXP_SUBSTR(line,'(.+?)(POBOX.*?)([0-9]([0-9\-]*[0-9])?)(.+)?',1,1,null,3) pobox
FROM the_table 
ORDER BY to_number(replace(substr(line,1,2),'.'))
```

Comment: Hey.. thanks for the help. This is working fine with the values that I have given.. But its failing for some other patterns.

Comment: Its failing for below values. '1. CORAL TECH PETER MAYNARD   CO BAY   DEVEAUX STREETS 2ND FLOOR POBOX N-1000'
'2. GULF OCEAN CENTRE - MONTAGU FORESHORE EAST BAY STREET POBOX SS -19084'
'3. AHMED SAEED DAMMAM 2044 31453 POBOX 011383-KSA  '
'4. MISR COMPRESSOR (CO) 10 TH OF INDUSTRIAL ZONE A-2 POBOX 1001'
'5. NOKIA AND NETWORKS OY C/O NSN FRANCE POBOX1 3 KARAPORTII '
'6. HEWLETT PACKARD EUROP BV POBOX 100- POBOX 100-CH-1217 '
'7. DUMONT BERGMAN BIDER + CO., S.C. POBOX456 DELEGACION CUAUHTEMO MX'...... Sorry I don't know how to post these values in code.

Comment: yes, that regular expression wouldn't work with that because the POBOX is not only made up by numbers now. We would need to know every possible POBOX format to come up with a regular expression

Comment: I have modified original question to add more examples. I think for now it covers most of the combination.

Comment: @VidyaPandey I just edited my answer to accommodate the new data you provided. It's working right now but it could not work with every pobox in your database